# FParsec stackoverflow in .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, fparsec

I use FParsec in *netstandard2.1* project (*StandartProj*) and use it from *netcoreapp2.0* (*CoreProj*).

```
// Standard Project
let parser = pfloat |>> (fun x -> x + 1)
let runParser str = run parser str

// Core Project
let parseResult = runParser "1" // StackOverflow exception
```

If I run parseResult it fails with *StackOverflow* exception, but if I use parser right in the *CoreProj* exception disappears:

```
// Standard Project
let parser = pfloat |>> (fun x -> x + 1)
let runCustomParser parser str = run parser str

// Core Project
let parseResult = runCustomParser parser "1" // Returns Success 2
```

So why this *StackOverflow* exception occures and how can I fix that without a crutch?

Update 1:

After fixing some problems with dependencies there is no problem with simple parser like `float`. But it seems like recursive parsers throws this error in runtime in case they can't be build. So far I have found fix by defining max recursive depth and setting all such parser calls with function like so:

```
let recursiveParser () =
    let rec _recParser depth =
        let simpleParser = ...
        if depth > maxDepth then simpleParser else recursiveParser() <|> simpleParser
    _recParser 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was referenced to recursive grammars, so even if recursive parser consumes input to inner parsers and only if they fails to it itself, it doesn't help.
So the code that helps

```
let recursiveParser () =
    let simpleParser = pfloat
    let rec _recParser () = simpleParser .>> >>= (fun x -> pstring "+" >>. _recParser () |>> (fun y -> ...)
    simpleParser <|> _recParser ()
```